# Which tools are there to create an illustration of a CNN, using a real input image as input?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am interested in making a scientific figure of my CNN and i want to use a real input image for illustration purposes.  [An example can be seen here (bottom figure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEBGg.png)

I only could find some tools which create a generic visualization of my model architecture.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.